# How do I get the EditText with the cursor in a list of EditTexts?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, cursor

[image: image1]

I have a popup dialog that allows a user to send multiple emails at once.

The top half is an array of EditTexts and the bottom half is a clickable list view with "suggested emails" I want the onItemClickEvent to put the suggested email to the "selected" EditText. isSelected() doesn't work, and isCursorVisible() is only API 16+ plus i'm not even sure that would solve my problem.

tl;dr How do I get the "selected" EditText out of an array of EditTexts?

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my own question for anyone seeking an answer to this problem in the future:

EditText.isSelected() is the correct method the EditText is just not automatically instantiated as the Selected view. Manually set the EditText as selected and it will function as expected.